# Can't copy files using the File System Object FileCopy method in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to loop through a table and copy the named files from there which are in a known copy to a project folder to automate a currently manual process. I've got the strings of what I want to copy and where to but I'm getting the 'Object doesn't support this method or property' on the FileCopy itself.  What I have is:

```
Sub OEMFileCopy()

Dim str, oem, oemArray() As String
Dim folderLetter, folder, oemFolder, company, copyFrom As String
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRow As Row
Dim myRng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim fso

oemFolder = "M:\Technical Support\Project Documentation\O.E.M Tech Literature"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTable.Cell(1, 1).Select

    str = Selection.Text
    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2) ' << remove end of cell characters

    ' Test maintenance table
    If (str Like "Manufacturer") Then
        For Each oRow In oTable.Rows

                Set myRng = oTable.Cell(oRow.Index, 3).Range
                myRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                oem = myRng.Text

                Set myRng = oTable.Cell(oRow.Index, 1).Range
                myRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                company = myRng.Text
                Debug.Print ("Company is " & company)


                If (Not ((oem Like "*O.E.M*") Or (oem Like "*OEM*") Or (oem Like "*WWW*") Or (oem Like "*www*"))) Then
                    oemArray() = Split(oem, ", ") '<< split into array of OEM filenames
                    For i = LBound(oemArray) To UBound(oemArray) '<< print each oem to output file
                        folderLetter = Left(oemArray(i), 1)
                        folder = ActiveDocument.Path & "\OEM Technical Literature\" & folderLetter & "\" & company

                        copyFrom = oemFolder & "\" & folderLetter & "\" & company & "\" & oemArray(i) & ".pdf"

                        If (fso.FolderExists(folder)) Then
                            folder = folder & "\"
                            fso.FileCopy copyFrom, folder
                        Else
                            fso.CreateFolder (folder)
                        End If

                    Next i
                End If




        Next oRow
    End If
Next oTable


End Sub
```

I've printed the copyFrom and folder and checked they exist. They look like:
copyFrom - M:\Technical Support\Project Documentation\O.E.M Tech Literature\A\ABB\A1285.pdf 
folder - folder M:\Technical Support\Project Documentation\2. Work in Progress\Current Projects\TEST\2. Draft Manuals\OEM Technical Literature\A\ABB\

The file doesn't already exist at the copy destination and the folder does exist.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that when defining multiples variable on the same line, you have to give the type for each variable. In your case, in `Dim folderLetter, folder, oemFolder, company, copyFrom As String`, only `copyFrom`is a String, other variables are Variant.

Comment: Thank you.  I had no idea that was the case.  I had something weird happening with one string variable and split them into the two lines and was wondering why that fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing your file copying commands:

- `FileCopy` is one of the commands available in the underlying VBA language.
- `CopyFile` is one of the methods available to a `FileSystemObject` object.

So, instead of using

```
fso.FileCopy copyFrom, folder
```

use

```
fso.CopyFile copyFrom, folder
```

instead.